# Android Studio missing design

Tags: android, android-studio

So my nephew clicked something while I was away from my workstation. 
I am a beginner at Android Development and still learning the environment of Android Studio.

Comparing the [1st Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j28JQ.jpg) it should like that unlike what happen to the [2nd Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BC9H.jpg).

What do I need to do to go back to the first Photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 tabs at the bottom. On one screen you are in the design editor, on the other screen you are on the text editor.

Comment: This answer my problem. Kudos for helping me understand this IDE. @Distwo